# Google Script SQL with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My issue is, I'm using the [yiono SCRIPT sql library](https://github.com/YionoFr/GoogleScriptSQL) and trying to integrate it with HTML but am having trouble with 2 pieces. Everything else is working beautifully.

For example
I want to make an HTML form to update the 'Pro' value on the row that 'ID' = '1'

It works beautifully when I run the function in IDE, but I don't know the best way to put these in as variables from an HTML page. I tried some silliness with GET requests but couldn't get it to work.

```
function update_row(){
  var SQL = new gSQL();
  SQL.DB('*redacted*').TABLE('DAILY-DATA').UPDATE('Pro').WHERE('ID', '=', '1').VALUES('KAOS').setVal();
}
```

Problem 1: Get form input into `.WHERE('ID', '=','from_html_form')` and I'd like to do it within the Google environment by way of web app.

Minimal Reproducible Example

Here is the function
[image]

Here is the result
[image]

Comment: I see. The code is added via text but, I forgot to link the library, my apologies. This is a bound script to the sheet, and here is the library github. [link](https://github.com/YionoFr/GoogleScriptSQL)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
function update_row(){
  var SQL = new gSQL();
  SQL.DB('*redacted*').TABLE('DAILY-DATA').UPDATE('Pro').WHERE('ID', '=', '1').VALUES('KAOS').setVal();
}
```

by

```
function update_row(input = '1'){
  var SQL = new gSQL();
  SQL.DB('*redacted*')
    .TABLE('DAILY-DATA')
    .UPDATE('Pro')
    .WHERE('ID', '=', input)
    .VALUES('KAOS')
    .setVal();
}
```

Main changes

1. added a parameter with a default value
2. Replaced a literal by the parameter
   NOTES: The breaklines are not really required, it's a matter of programming style.

Add the below simple trigger to a .gs file in your Google Apps Script project.

```js
function doGet(e){
  const html = `
    <input type="number" />
    <button onClick="myFunction();">Submit</button>
    <script>
      function myFunction(){
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(()=> {
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerText = 'Done!'
            document
             .body
             .appendChild(div)
           }) 
    .update_row(document.querySelector('input').value);
   }
   </script>`
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```

To test this you will have to deploy as web app. Please follow the instructions for this on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=en#forms

Comment: Wow, lemme take a run at it and I'll let you know what happens!

Comment: I believe I have the code correct, and it runs with no errors, but does not update the sheet. 

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SQB-5V15QrGRO1gajTsNAkXJ2Q0cBjSO2z4anPtKgLo/edit?usp=sharing)Here is the sheet

[link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzOwEs70BnrHaJRQPPhLwJrSlC2DdAVChs4-Atkmlyv0Xg_l3v7JEdmXl5WNGwL3YtlXg/exec)Here is the Web_App

I added your code to trigger.gs and all runs without error, and shows 'Done' but no change in sheet.

Comment: Nevermind lol. I got it! Looks like its working.